# Using a list of lists containing indexes to pull strings by index from another list

Tags: python, string, list, indexing

I have a list of lists that contain integers. These integers are indexes for each element in the list of strings. I need to use the list of indexes to select the correct string from the list of strings; creating a new list of lists of the just the selected strings. Sorry for the tongue twister of an explanation, I tried to make it is clear as possible. Below is a simple example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
list_of_indexes=[[0,2,4],[5,7,6],[1,9]]

list_of_text=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

desired_output = [['a','c','e'], ['f', 'h', 'g'], ['b', 'j']]
```

Comment: Note that Python is zero-indexed. So your desired index of 1, corresponding to `'a'`, should really be 0.

Comment: I did write code, it was rubbish, so I made an easy example instead. I knew I would get this comment, but it was worth the risk of a downvote; I received a great, efficient solution. I usually do provide code I attempt, which can be found by viewing my other asked questions, but in this case it wasn't worth anything (I was very far off and couldn't conceptualize the logic properly). Thank you, for the zero-index reminder, I edited my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
[[list_of_text[idx-1] for idx in indices] for indices in list_of_indexes]
```